# Are constants for NaN, NEGATIVE_INFINITY, POSITIVE_INFINITY available in Apex logic for Double?

Tags: apex, double

Based on this [java.lang.Double](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Double-source.html) source code I tried to get these constants to use in an Apex port of a Java open source algorithm:

```
private static final Double DOUBLE_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = Double.valueOf(-1.0) / Double.valueOf(0.0);
private static final Double DOUBLE_POSITIVE_INFINITY = Double.valueOf(1.0) / Double.valueOf(0.0);
private static final Double DOUBLE_NaN = Double.valueOf(0.0) / Double.valueOf(0.0);
```

but all of these report a `System.MathException: Divide by 0`.

Is there a way to reference these values in Apex?

Comment: [Moving discussion to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139613/discussion-on-question-by-keith-c-are-constants-for-nan-negative-infinity-posi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way of creating the infinity constants which is the main part of what I need:

```
final Double POSITIVE_INFINITY = Math.pow(10, 300) / Math.pow(10, -300);
final Double NEGATIVE_INFINITY = -POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

allowing:

```
private static Boolean isFinite(Double d) {
    return d != null && d != POSITIVE_INFINITY && d != NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

but didn't find a way of creating NaN as these all throw exceptions rather than produce the NaN result:

```
0.0 / 0.0
Math.sqrt(-1)
Math.mod(10.0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't have very many constants at all, aside from the system [enums](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_enums.htm), two constants in Math (E and PI), that's about it. You'll need to adjust the algorithm to detect those conditions directly. I'd probably create some kind of enum.

```
public enum DOUBLE_STATE { NEGATIVE_INFINITY, POSITIVE_INFINITY, NAN }
```